# Where to start learning more about wordpress templates

Tags: functions, dropdown

i made a website for a sport club, since it had to be a wordpress i converted my html/css into a wordpress template following [this guide](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/):

the layout and functions work, but i have no idea how or where i can learn to add more. Like the dropdown does not work, i don't know how to add a page indicate after x post are shown to go to the next few post.. etc

Is there a place where i can lean this?

I'm having trouble getting this menu:

[image]

right now my header looks like this:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md justify-content-center">
    <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/nav/logo.png" alt="logo" class="ml-5 mr-3">
    <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">Flybird Airlines</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar3">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto justify-content-end">
           <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

this just displays all the links vertical

Comment: there is a lot of informations in the codex : https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: @mmm yes, thank. There i found how to display my page's i made in wordpress. but i can't seem to find how to make a dropdown of them.

Comment: I don't understand where do you want to display a dropdown menu ? edit you question to add more details or an example.

Comment: @mmm i updated my main post, mybe its more clear now.